# ACE/TAO build an rpm after sucessful make

Tags: rpmbuild, ace, tao

ACE and TAO is used for our deployment and they will be required to be packaged as RPM from now on (for SUSE platform if it matters).
While I know there are RPM files available we have some specific "$ACE_ROOT/include/makeinclude/platform_macros.GNU" file that we use and we would like to have the RPM build out of the binaries resulted from our own build.

Can we create an RPM after following the steps from ACE-INSTALL.html, based on that build output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [ACE_wrappers/rpmbuild](https://github.com/DOCGroup/ACE_TAO/tree/master/ACE/rpmbuild) for the spec file that is used for all RPMs on OpenSuSE Build service. Couldn't you extend that script with the options you need and contribute that back into the main github repo?

Comment: Ok, thanks for the confirmation. I will have a look and see if I can contribute.